# HTML, How do I left justify a picture even though im using CID?

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

I am trying to create an interface for emails. I want to import a picture but I can't do it without having cid. For example:

That works just fine. but i Can't seem to put the text to the left of the picture.  Please look at the code below to get a better understanding!

```
<div style="background-color:black;">
<body style="font-color:white;">
    <h1><i>Airline Credits</i></h1>
    </br>
    </ul>
    Dear [FullName],<br/>
    Thank you for your <i>Airline Credits</i> redemption. Below is a summary of your order:

    <b>Order Date:</b>[OrderDate]<br/>
    <b>Description:</b>[ItemName]
    <br/><b>Redemption Amount:</b>[CostInPoints]
    <br/><b>Order Tracking Number:</b>[OrderNumber]

    <br/><br/>
    <b>Please note:</b>
    If you did not make this request, please contact us immediately at [AirlinePhoneNumber]. Our Customer Service Representatives are available to help you.

    <br/><br/>
    Please read the terms and conditions for Airline Credits Redemptions at <a href="[WebSiteAddress]">[WebSiteAddress]</a> about how you are provided your redeemed items. To view your Airline Credits balance, please <a href="[EMLink]">click here</a>
    <br/>
    <img src=cid:AirlineCredits.jpg/>
</body>
</div>
```

Comment: is this markup for html-email? or is it on a webpage?

Answer (score 3):

HTML email is pain - nothing inherent in it, but because Microsoft decided to make Outlook 2007, 2010, and 2013 use Word's horribly broken and poor HTML rendering implementation (whereas Outlook 2003 used IE's).

Outlook has poor floating box support, so I advise against it in this situation.

Anyway, ordinarily I'm a web-standards zealot - but in HTML email that doesn't really seem to matter, so I'd just say to use tables, like so:

```
<table border="0"> <!-- Tim Berners-Lee, forgive me, for I have sinned. -->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>Please read the terms and conditions for Airline Credits Redemptions at <a   href="[WebSiteAddress]">[WebSiteAddress]</a> about how you are provided your redeemed items. To view your Airline Credits balance, please <a href="[EMLink]">click here</a></p>
        </td>
        <td> <img src=cid:AirlineCredits.jpg /> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Relatively painless, gets the job done.

(and causes me to die inside).

Comment: Yes. Tables are the thing you should use in emails. It's a pain in the a**, but thats the way it is.